# Load TinyMCE 6.8 from Public Directory

Tags: javascript, tinymce-6

When loading tinymce as javascript files from the server's *public/scripts* directory the assets load in the browser but the editor pane doesn't show on the page.

[image: Files Successfully Load]

The editor pane `<div>` and nested `<iframe>` are created on the page but the parent `<div>` is styled to be hidden.

When I change the visibility to be visible it shows up as a basic and functioning editor on the page but without any styling.

[image: Basic Editor Pane]

My config and html are as basic as possible.

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
  });
</script>
<body>
  <textarea>
    Welcome to TinyMCE!
  </textarea>
<body>
```

In contrast, when I load tinymce from the CDN with the *API_Key*, and when I load it from *Node_Modules* directory as static files using ExpressJs it works exactly as advertised.

I've tried:

- Using the NPM version and copying the files from the *Node_Modules* directory to *public/scripts* to see if that release works.
- Changing the scripts directory from *public/scripts* to *public/js* to see if there are any hardcoded dependency paths that require the default naming convention.

I appreciate guidance from anyone who has made this work or has insight into what I am missing.
Thank you!